Robinson Approximation for the exchange integral
I am trying to deduce Robinson approximation for the exchange integral in Hartree-Fock equation (https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.9.215), but without success. I obtained the expression for a shielded uniform electron-gas, below:
\begin{equation}
 X_{ELB} = \frac{-2}{\pi}\left\{ \left(\frac{k_{TF}^2+k_F^2-k_m^2}{4k_m}\right) \mathrm{ln}\left[\frac{k_{TF}^2+(k_m + k_F)^2}{k_{TF}^2+(k_m - k_F)^2}\right] +  k_F  - k_{TF} \ \left[ \mathrm{tg^{-1}}\left(\frac{k_m - k_F}{k_{TF}}\right) + \mathrm{tg^{-1}}\left(\frac{k_m+k_F}{k_{TF}}\right)\right]\right\}
\end{equation}
Now, I need to solve the follow equation to find Robinson approximation:
\begin{equation}
    X_R = \frac{\int_0^{k_F} X_{ELB} \ d \vec{k}_m}{\int_0^{k_F} \ d \vec{k}_m}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation*}
    X_R = \frac{4\pi \int_0^{k_F} X_{ELB} k_m^2 \ d \vec{k}_m}{\frac{4 \pi k_F^3}{3}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    X_R = \frac{3}{k_F^3}\int_0^{k_F} X_{ELB} k_m^2 \ d \vec{k}_m
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\hspace{-2.0em}
    X_R = \frac{3}{k_F^3}\int_0^{k_F} -\frac{2}{\pi}\left\{\left[\frac{k^2_{TF}+k_F^2 - k_m^2}{4k_m}\right] \mathrm{ln}\left[\frac{k_{TF}^2 + (k_m+k_F)^2}{k^2_{TF}+(k_m-k_F)^2}\right]+ k_F - k_{TF}\left[tg^{-1}\left(\frac{k_m + k_F}{k_{TF}}\right)-tg^{-1}\left(\frac{k_m-k_F}{k_{TF}}\right)\right]\right\} k_m^2 \ d k_m
\end{equation*}
I found this last equation, but I have no idea how to solve this integral.
After solving this integral, I suppose to find the same equation present in the article. Can anyone help me with this problem?
